# Seeking GM-level coverage of a typical pawn structure

Tags: pawn-structure

I was wondering if there is a top level coverage of plans for Black in the below pawn structure:

```
[fen "8/pp3ppp/2p2p2/8/3P4/8/PPP2PPP/8 w - - 0 1"]
```

Or this one:

```
[fen "8/pp3ppp/2p2p2/8/2PP4/8/PP3PPP/8 w - - 0 1"]
```

I know similar ones arise from Caro-Kann, but have also seen it in many other openings where White plays Bxf6.

Computer claims equality, or a slight edge, but I would like to "hear an opinion" from top GMs if possible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Vallejo has a great series (Spanish only) in chess24 about the Caro-Pirc, which covers this particular structure. Note that the dynamics of positions with those two pawn structures are probably very different from one another (a ...c5 break by Black would have a very different impact on each case. Similar ofr the pressure on the semi-open d file)

"Engine claims equality" does not make much sense when referring to the pawn structure itself, since many different factors will determine the actual evaluation of a given position.

Comment: I would guess that the pawn structure showed above with only kings on the board is winning for white, but I'm not certain. Certainly white is pushing for the win.

Comment: With kings only, sure. White has a huge advantage but Black will definitely fight hard to avoid reaching a situation like that